# How to down load image form the text file and give the name in the text file

Tags: python, import, google-colaboratory

I have a text file that contains several ids and links associate with that id, the link represents the images. now I want to download this image using this link and name the downloaded image with the corresponding ID, how to do this in python.

below is the same of the first lines in the text

000000001,[image_link]
[image]

```
import os.path
import urllib.request
links = open('/content/photos/photos.txt', 'r')
for link in links:
    link = link.strip()
    name = link.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
    filename = os.path.join('downloads', name)
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print('Downloading: ' + filename)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename)
        except Exception as inst:
            print(inst)
            print('  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.')
```

Comment: URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: 000214617,http>

Comment: It means your url is not valid. Paste the url of any sample from your csv

Comment: I have added the sceen shot of the text file.  the URL are valid.

Comment: You are splitting the line incorrectly, try splitting it from , not by /. Your link is the complete line with the ID that’s why it’s giving this URLError

Comment: Try printing the link variable which you are calling you’ll see it’s not valid

Comment: `tamaraberg.com/street2shop/wheretobuyit/photos.tar` . I used this link for downloading the .tar file after unzipping I extracted text file which includes img id and  a alink to down load the img.

Answer (score 0):

here the solution.

```
import os.path
import urllib.request
links = open('./photos.txt', 'r')
for link in links:
    link = link.strip()
    name ,link = link.rsplit(',',-1) # name of file
    
    filename = os.path.join('downloads', name)
    
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        print('Downloading: ' + filename)
        try:
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename)
        except Exception as inst:
            
            print(inst)
            print('  Encountered unknown error. Continuing.')
```

just update the split. make sure you have the save path present there.

Comment: its still not working.  error is no such file or directory exists. I have copied the path of the file properly.

Comment: Is it for the photos.txt cause I’ve changed it as per my directory. You have to change it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two problems here:

- the way you are splitting the line, since the line is comma separated it should be:

  `name ,link = line.split(',')`
- your `downloads` directory doesn't exist yet, you should create it with:

  `os.makedirs('downloads', exist_ok=True)`

Here is my code example:

```
import os
import urllib.request

images_dir = 'downloads' 
os.makedirs(images_dir, exist_ok=True)

with open('/content/photos/photos.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        name, link = line.split(',') 
        filename = os.path.join(images_dir, name + '.jpg')
        if  not os.path.isfile(filename):
            print('Downloading: ' + filename)
            try:
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename)
            except Exception as inst:
                print(inst)
```